# What are the different eclipse shortcuts available?

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanted to know the different eclipse shortcuts available like when we wanted to write this

`System.out.println();` then we simply write `syso` and hit `ctrl+space`
then we get System.out.println();.I do not want shortcuts like for copy ctrl+c or to cut ctrl +X

screenshot of templates

[image]

Comment: ctrl+shift+f - format, ctrl+shift+o-import all...
http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key refer this link. Many are there like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are called "editor templates", and you can see the full list in

```
Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Editor --> Templates
```

You can also create your own there, with various placeholders, e.g. I have one `isequalto` defined like this:

```
${:importStatic(org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat)}assertThat(${actual}).isEqualTo(${expected});
```

This will automatically add a static import and add cursor positions that can be navigated to with TAB.  This can be invoked by typing `isequalto` (or just `ise`) and ctrl+SPACE.

For a try/catch bock, just type `try` and ctrl+SPACE.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcuts your referring to are called templates.

You can view them all in the IDE or make your own:

> Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates

Basically to use any of these templates, type their name followed by `CTRL` + `SPACE`.  Once you have enough of the name typed that the name is distinct, for instance `syso` you can use `CTRL` + `SPACE`.  So you may not need to type the whole name.

Comment: I went throgh as you have said and attached the same in screenshot.But i do not know how to use.Like for system.out.println() syso+ctrl+space.Similarily for try/catch block what should i do

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are not shortcuts, but Templates.

Open Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates and you'll see the full list.

You can even add your own templates.

Comment: how to use templates?Suppose for try/catch what should i do like ctrl+space for System.out.println().Please see the screesnhot.

Comment: For try catch use this    try {
 ${line_selection}${cursor}
} catch (${Exception} ${exception_variable_name}) {
 // ${todo}: handle exception
}

Comment: And write try then press ctrl+space

Answer (score 1):

GO to Help Menu in Eclipse

[image]

And Click Key Assist

[image]

Comment: Those are the shortcuts the OP specifically mentioned he's not interested in.

Comment: @Rakesh These are shortcuts but I need templates.Well your answer will be helpful for future users those who need shortcuts for eclipse.So +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

see [Eclipse Short Cuts](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_%283.0%29.pdf)

It may be for Eclipse 3 but those shortcuts have been standardised for a while.