# Can I define a custom keyboard shortcut in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I have to insert a special string in my code in a large scale.

Can I define a short key in Eclipse for inserting a special string in my code?

I need `Copy` and `Paste` keys so I don't want to use `Copy` and `Paste` operations.

For example I need to press `ALT+CTRL+K` and the text "hello" is inserted.

Comment: do you mean templates?may be you are looking this type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868490/what-are-the-different-eclipse-shortcuts-available